# WPF Command Binding - Cannot find source for binding with reference

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, command

I have tried to bind the command of the button in the view to another class in the view model. However I'm getting the below error:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference

Is there something wrong with my binding? Really appreciate it if anyone could help. Thanks a lot.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            _canExecute = true;
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        }

        private ICommand _clickCommand;
        public ICommand ClickCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _clickCommand ?? (_clickCommand = new CommandHandler(() => MyAction(), _canExecute));
            }
        }
        private bool _canExecute;
        public void MyAction()
        {
            Print();
        }
    }
}

public class CommandHandler: ICommand
{
    private Action _action;
    private bool _canExecute;
    public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged{
    add{CommandManager.RequerySuggested+=value;}remove{CommandManager.RequerySuggested-=value;}
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid> 
        <Button Height="50" Command="{Binding ClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Class1}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Class1 doesn't lies in Visual tree of button*** and hence cannot bind to it using **RelativeSource**.

If you have set DataContext to Class1, all you need is simple binding and binding engine automatically will resolve it for you.

```
<Button Height="50" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
```

---

In case you haven't set DataContext, set it first like this:

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
     <local:Class1/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Grid> 
    <Button Height="50" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
  </Grid>

</Window>
```

---

In case you don't want to bind DataContext, you have to declare Class1 instance as a resource and access it to bind to command.

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
     <local:Class1 x:Key="class1"/>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid> 
    <Button Height="50"
            Command="{Binding ClickCommand, Source={StaticResource class1}}"/>
  </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I didn't use the datacontext = new Class1 is because I have other datacontexts in all parts of the project so I can't just use datacontext for local:Class1. Instead using Command="{Binding ClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Class1}}}". Do you know any other way to do this datacontext? @Rohit Vats

Comment: I have updated answer with another approach. See if that works for you.